# Issue using StreamReader to replicate Vlookup on multiple columns per row

Tags: powershell, csv, streamreader

I have one very large pipe delimited file (~million rows) that contains 11 columns, 8 of which contain a key.

### Master_File.csv

```
Year|Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4|Key5|Key6|Key7|Key8|Location|Name
2019|1235|2345|1231|1235|3536|1231|1234|3624|Site6|Storage
2019|2345|2345|1231|1231|3536|1235|1234|1231|Site8|Storage
2019|3536|2345|3536|1235|2345|1235|3536|1235|Site7|Storage
2019|2345|1235|1231|1235|1231|3452|1231|2345|Site9|Storage
```

I have another small pipe delimited file (~8k rows) that contains 2 columns, the key and a value.

### Lookup_File.csv

```
Key|Value
1235|Value 1235
2345|Value 2345
1231|Value 1231
1234|Value 1234
3536|Value 3536
3452|Value 3452
1234|Value 1234
3624|Value 3624
```

I need to loop through each row of the Master_File.csv and replace the Key with the Value in the Lookup_File.csv.  The result should look like this.

```
Year|Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4|Key5|Key6|Key7|Key8|Location|Name
2019|Value 1235|Value 2345|Value 1231|Value 1235|Value 3536|Value 1231|Value 1234|Value 3624|Site6|Storage
2019|Value 2345|Value 2345|Value 1231|Value 1231|Value 3536|Value 1235|Value 1234|Value 1231|Site8|Storage
2019|Value 3536|Value 2345|Value 3536|Value 1235|Value 2345|Value 1235|Value 3536|Value 1235|Site7|Storage
2019|Value 2345|Value 1235|Value 1231|Value 1235|Value 1231|Value 3452|Value 1231|Value 2345|Site9|Storage
```

The code below is what I have so far, but the issue is that it just runs through the Master_File once, replacing only the first Key.

```
$content = "c:\Lookup_File.csv"
$LookupFile = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader - ArgumentList $content
$skip1 = $LookupFile.ReadLine()

$src = "c:\Master_File.csv"
$MasterFile = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $src

$header = $Masterfile.ReadLine()
$outData = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
[void]$outData.AppendLine($header)

while ($line = $LookupFile.ReadLine())
{
    $key = ($line -split "\|")[0]
    $value = ($line -split "\|")[1]
    while ($row = $MasterFile.ReadLine()){
        $row = $row -Replace $key, $value
        [void]$outData.AppendLine($row)
    }
}
$outData.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath "c:\Master_File_Out.csv" -Encoding ascii
```

I'm getting this as the output.

```
Year|Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4|Key5|Key6|Key7|Key8|Location|Name
2019|Value 1235|2345|1231|Value 1235|3536|1231|1234|3624|Site7|Storage
2019|2345|2345|1231|1231|3536|Value 1235|1234|1231|Site8|Storage
2019|3536|2345|3536|Value 1235|2345|Value 1235|3536|Value 1235|Site9|Storage
2019|2345|Value 1235|1231|Value 1235|1231|3452|1231|2345|Site11|Storage
```

I'm really struggling to loop through each row of the Master_File and replace each of the 8 keys with the value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might run into issues with your Key not being unique (i.e., "1234" is listed twice).

Comment: Treat the files as `.csv` files and use `Import-Csv`/`Export-Csv` (with -Delimiter '|'), on reading Lookup_File.csv build a HashTable. Then iterate Master_File.csv and replace  field values from the HashTable.

Comment: Sorry, the duplicate Key is a type-o in my sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, try:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\26\SO_57659677.ps1

$hash = @{}
Import-Csv '.\Lookup_File.csv' -Delimiter '|' | ForEach {$Hash[$_.Key]=$_.Value}

$Master = Import-Csv '.\Master_File.csv' -Delimiter '|'

ForEach($Item in $Master){
    For($i=1;$i -le 8;$i++){
       if($hash.ContainsKey($item."Key$i")){
           $item."Key$i" = $hash[$item."Key$i"]
       }
    }
}

$Master |ft -auto

# $Master | Export-Csv "c:\Master_File_Out.csv" -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation 
# To have no double quotes in the ouptput file
# ($Master | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"' | Set-Content -"c:\Master_File_Out.csv" Encoding ascii
```

Sample output:

```
> $Master|ft -auto

Year Key1       Key2       Key3       Key4       Key5       Key6       Key7       Key8       Location
---- ----       ----       ----       ----       ----       ----       ----       ----       --------
2019 Value 1235 Value 2345 Value 1231 Value 1235 Value 3536 Value 1231 Value 1234 Value 3624 Site6
2019 Value 2345 Value 2345 Value 1231 Value 1231 Value 3536 Value 1235 Value 1234 Value 1231 Site8
2019 Value 3536 Value 2345 Value 3536 Value 1235 Value 2345 Value 1235 Value 3536 Value 1235 Site7
2019 Value 2345 Value 1235 Value 1231 Value 1235 Value 1231 Value 3452 Value 1231 Value 2345 Site9
```

## EDIT

added a level of abstraction by reading the ColumnNames into an array and use index 1..8

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\26\SO_57659677_2.ps1
$hash = @{}
Import-Csv '.\Lookup_File.csv' -Delimiter '|' | ForEach {$Hash[$_.Key]=$_.Value}

$Master = Import-Csv '.\Master_File.csv' -Delimiter '|'
$ColNames = $Master[0].psobject.properties.name

ForEach($Item in $Master){
    For($i=1;$i -le 8;$i++){
       if($hash.ContainsKey($item."$($ColNames[$i])")){
           $item."$($ColNames[$i])" = $hash[$item."$($ColNames[$i])"]
       }
    }
}

$Master |ft -auto
```

---

```
> .\SO_57659677_2.ps1

Year Working    Approved   Rejected   WhatIf1    Whatif2    Submitted  Proposed   Syncd      Location
---- -------    --------   --------   -------    -------    ---------  --------   -----      --------
2019 Value 1235 Value 2345 Value 1231 Value 1235 Value 3536 Value 1231 Value 1234 Value 3624 Site6
2019 Value 2345 Value 2345 Value 1231 Value 1231 Value 3536 Value 1235 Value 1234 Value 1231 Site8
2019 Value 3536 Value 2345 Value 3536 Value 1235 Value 2345 Value 1235 Value 3536 Value 1235 Site7
2019 Value 2345 Value 1235 Value 1231 Value 1235 Value 1231 Value 3452 Value 1231 Value 2345 Site9
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  I was trying to figure out the "key$i" part.  I might use foreach-object so I could pipe that to export-csv.

Comment: As written in my explanation this works.  However, I over simplified my sample data.  The Key columns in the Master file do not contain sequential numbers.  They are snapshots of data.  The headers are actually like this Year, Working, Approved, Rejected, WhatIf1, Whatif2, Submitted, Proposed, Syncd, Location.

Comment: So how do you want to address the columns? 2nd..9th column? Treating the whole row as text isn't a good idea when the 1st column year might interfere with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same thing.

```powershell
$hash=@{}
import-csv lookup_file.csv -delimiter '|' | foreach {
  $hash[$_.key] = $_.value
}

import-csv master_file.csv -delimiter '|' | foreach {
  foreach ($i in 1..8) {
    $_."key$i" = $hash[$_."key$i"]
  }
  $_
} | export-csv master_file_out.csv -delimiter '|'
```